# Eclipse source folder not recognized

Tags: java, eclipse, file-io

I would like to create a separate folder for my resources in a Java project. How, in the name of God do I achieve such a simple thing ? I have been trying to get it to work for quite some time now and it starts to drive me nuts. Here is what I have tried so far:

1) I opened my Build Path Settings and added a folder to my source folders called "resources".

2) I added two folders to that folder called "font" and "img" containing images and font files.

3) I try to access those files in code like this:

getClassLoader() is said to give me an absolute path, so I take a path without the leading `/`:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/font/MyFont.otf")
```

which returns null. Why is file management in eclipse so infuriating ?

Comment: Is "resources" outside the "src" folder?

Comment: @gtgaxiola Yes and I would like to keep it like that.

Comment: ../resources/font/MyFont.otf

Comment: Did you change your build path to src/resources..? In that case you need to give path as font/MyFont.otf

Comment: as mentioned above, since you are not in the "src" folder, you need to go a level up or some levels up depending on the location of the resource you want to load: getResourceAsStream("../../resources/font...);

Comment: @bgamlath I think that worked. I have absolutely no idea why... Can somebody please explain ?

Comment: getResourceAsStream always look in the classpath which is src folder by default, you are just providing a relative path from src folder. This is one way of doing it but if you want to keep the resource folder also in classpath you can check my answer below that will also work.

Comment: In eclipse, the build path is also the class path. http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_classpath.htm
Therefore, that will be considered as the root folder for classes. All resource relative paths are computed relative to that folder and the package of the class. If your class is in default package, the full path will be classpath + relative path.

Comment: @bgamlath I do not understand why I do NOT have to write the suggested `../resources/font...`, or if it were absolute (including src's parent folder), why not `resources/font/...` As far as I know, it goes ahead and looks for files in the `src` folder which is in no way connected to the resources folder other than that they share the same parent directory. This is just utterly confusing and nerve wrecking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have added 'resources' folder as a source folder in the build path settings you should be able to load the fonts like below.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("font/MyFont.otf")
```

Once you specify the 'resources' folder as a source folder eclipse included it in the root of the class path for java. So you only need the path relative to the resources folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for you. Should work

Step 1:

```
InputStream is =  this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("font/MyFont.otf");
```

Step 2:

In Eclipse

```
run > run configurations > classpath > select user entries > advanced > add folders > select resource folder
```

After this Run the project. The reason is the resource folder needs to be in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/font/MyFont.otf")
```